# Node js - problem inplementing Inquirer.js for CLI app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface, inquirerjs

I'm having problems getting inquirer.js to work smoothly in a simple CLI that I'm working on. First, the prompt question repeats several times and this needs to be fixed. Second, I wrote the  code as a class within a module, but didn't need to include the code to make it a module here, so just included the class code below. In the code below I am trying to get access to the users selected choice from the inquirer.js prompt but I'm not able to log the user's selected answer to console. I'm attempting to write a Class here so I can just instantiate an object anytime I need inquirer.js functionality and just changing certain properties to customize the prompt. I'm also using a couple extra modules Colors.js and Shell.js Any help from some knowledgeable programmers is greatly appreciated by me and I thank you for the help :)

Here is my code so far:

> ```
>     /* See Examples Below To Test This Class */
> ```

```
const inquirer = require('inquirer');
const sh = require('shelljs');
const colors = require('./colors');
const color = colors.color;

// class to instantiate an inquirer prompt
class PromptQue {
  constructor(pP) { // pP is an passed Object of params {key:value pairs}
    this.pP = pP;
    this.answer = undefined; // a class property to hold user's answer to prompt
    this.clearTerm = false; // set true if need to clear user window after prompt
    this.promptColor = color.tan; // assign a color to prompt question text from colors.js
    this.statusBar = new inquirer.ui.BottomBar();
    this.doStatusMsg = false; // set true if need to display status message
    this.statusColor = color.warning; // assign a color to status message text from colors.js
    this.statusMsg = undefined; // assign a status message
    // this.choicesColor = color.offwhite;

    // the switch below tests whether a normal Array
    // or an Assoc Array Object was passed as answer 'choices'
    switch(pP.hasOwnProperty('choices')) {
      case true:
        let testIfArray = Array.isArray(this.pP.choices);
        if(!testIfArray) { // if not Array convert 'choices' object to array
          this.pP.choices = this.GenArr(pP.choices);
        }
      case false:
        break;
    }

    this.updateParams(); // call to set colors/styles on color enabled params
  }

// ### !!! -----------------  DEBUG THIS!  ------------------------------ >>>

// ### !!! Prompt() Method: Can't Get The Answer Returned !! ------ ###
  // call Prompt() method to run the PromptQue instance
  Prompt() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // doStatusMsg is set true, display status message
      this.checkStatusMsg();
      inquirer.prompt([
        this.pP // this is the Object Params passed to constructor
      ]).then((answer) => { // getting user's answer to prompt
        this.answer = answer[this.pP.name];
        return this.answer;
      }).catch((err) => {console.log(err)});
    })
    .then(() => this.clearStatus())
    .then(() => this.clear(this.clearTerm)); // if true : clear user window after prompt
  }
```

````
> ```
    // CONTINUING CODE :::::::::::
    // ### !!! -----------------  DEBUG THIS!  ------------------------------ >>>

      showData() {
        let keys = Object.keys(this.pP);
        keys.forEach((key) => {
          if(key === 'choices') {
            let arr = this.pP['choices'];
            let choicesStr = '';
            let cntr = 0;
            arr.forEach((val) => {
                if(cntr < this.pP['choices'].length) {
                  choicesStr += `${val}, `;
                } else {
                  choicesStr += `${val}`;
                }
                cntr++;
            });
            console.log(color.gray(`choices: ${choicesStr}`));
          } else {
            console.log(color.gray(`${key}: ${this.pP[key]}`));
          }
        });
        console.log(color.gray(`clearTerm: ${this.clearTerm}`));
        let C = this.promptColor('#COLOR');
        console.log(color.gray(`promptColor: ${C}`));
        console.log(color.gray(`statusMsg: ${this.statusMsg}`));
        console.log(color.gray(`doStatusMsg ${this.doStatusMsg}`));
        C = this.statusColor('#COLOR');
        console.log(color.gray(`statusColor: ${C}`));
      }

      // function to convert object into regular array
      GenArr(arr) {
        let regArr = [];
        for(var key in arr) {
          var value = arr[key];
          regArr.push(value);
        }
        return regArr;
      }

      // rebuilds colored enabled params with specified colors/styles
      updateParams() {
        let keys = Object.keys(this.pP);
        keys.forEach((key) => {
          switch (key) {
            case 'message':
              this.pP['message'] = this.promptColor(this.pP['message']);
              break;
          }
        });

        if(this.statusMsg) {
          this.statusMsg = this.statusColor(this.statusMsg);
        }
      }

      // displays a new message (msg) in the Status Bar
      checkStatusMsg() {
        if(this.doStatusMsg) {
          let msg = `${this.statusColor.bold(this.statusMsg)}\n`;
          this.setStatus(msg);
        }
      }

      // Set a status message for the prompt
      setStatus(msg) {
        this.statusBar.updateBottomBar(msg);
        // return msg;
      }

      // Clears the Status Bar's Field
      clearStatus() {this.statusBar.updateBottomBar('')}

      // Method to get user's selected choice for this prompt
      getAnswer() {
        return this.answer;
      }

      // console.log the user's selected choice for this prompt, mainly for debugging
      logAnswer() {
        if(this.answer !== undefined) {
          console.log(color.ltgray.italic.bold(`User Choice: ${this.answer}`));
        }
      }

      // function to clear user terminal screen
      clear(bool) {
        if(bool) {
          sh.exec('clear');
        }
      }
    }

    /////***********  CODE-END  ***********/////



    //----------- Test Code Below ---------------------

    /////****  TESTING ABOVE CODE  ****/////

    const sizeList = {0:'Jumbo',1:'Large',2:'Standard',3:'Medium',4:'Small',5:'Micro'};
    // create an object to pass to new instance

    // SETTING UP PROMPT HERE
    let cPromptData = {
      type: 'list',
      message: color.tan('What size Pizza do you need?'),
      name: 'pizza',
      choices: sizeList
    };
    let cPrompt = new PromptQue(cPromptData);
    cPrompt.statusMsg = 'Pizza! I Love Pizza!';
    cPrompt.doStatusMsg = true;

    // CALLING PROMPT
    cPrompt.Prompt();


    //-----------------------------------------------------

    const myPromise = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      cPrompt.Prompt();
    }).then(() => console.log(`Selected: ${cPrompt.answer}`));
    myPromise.then(() => console.log(`Selected: ${cPrompt.answer}`));

    // TRYING TO ASSIGN USER'S ANSWER HERE AND LOG TO CONSOLE! *NOT WORKING
    let ans = cPrompt.Prompt();
    console.log(`Selected: ${ans}`);
````

Here is Colors Module Code:

```
const __MODULEINFO__ = {
    package: 'lib',
    name: 'colors',
    sub: 'cli colors & styles',
    context: 'Colors & Styles module that utilizes Chalk JS',
    version: '1.0.0',
    dependencies: ['chalk.js'],
}
exports.MODULEINFO = __MODULEINFO__;
/*//// Module Introspection Stuff - End ////*/


/////***********  CODE-START  ***********/////

const chalk = require('chalk');

/* COLOR/STYLES INITIALIZE */
// white
const white = chalk.white;
// offwhite
const offwhite = chalk.hex('#f2f2d9');
// blue
const blue = chalk.hex('#0033ff');
// tan
const tan = chalk.hex('#cca26c');
// green
const green = chalk.hex('#009900');
// ltgray
const ltgray = chalk.hex('#d9d9d9');
// gray
const gray = chalk.hex('#808080');
// error
const alert = chalk.hex('#ff0000');
// warning
const warning = chalk.hex('#ff5c00');

//* ** COLOR-STYLES ** *//
const color = {
  white: white,
  blue: blue,
  tan: tan,
  green: green,
  ltgray: ltgray,
  gray: gray,
  alert: alert,
  warning: warning,
}

exports.color = color;


/////***********  CODE-END  ***********/////

/* *****  DEV NOTES  ***** /*

// NEEDS MORE WORK!

// add any of these colors/styles or add custom ones:

// turqoise
turq: chalk.hex('#02B388');
bgturq: chalk.whiteBright.bgHex('#00624F');
// info: blue
info: chalk.hex('#0092ff');
bginfo: chalk.white.bgHex('#285095');
// warning: orange
warn: chalk.hex('#ff8700');
bgwarn: chalk.whiteBright.bgHex('#ce6d00');
// error: red
error: chalk.hex('#ff0000');
bgerror: chalk.whiteBright.bgHex('#eb0000');
// dim: grey
grey: chalk.hex('#a1a1a1');
bggrey: chalk.hex('#a1a1a1').bgHex('#2d2d2d');
// dim: tan
tan: tan = chalk.hex('#cca26c');
bgtan: chalk.hex('#cca26c').bgHex('#3b2b1c');
// yellow
yellow: chalk.hex('#fff500');
bgyellow: chalk.whiteBright.bgHex('#e6c200');
// dark
dark: chalk.hex('#000000');
bgdark: chalk.hex('#000000').bgHex('#747474');
darkbold: chalk.hex('#000000').bold;
bgdarkbold: chalk.hex('#000000').bgHex('#747474').bold;
// red bold
redbold: chalk.red.bold;
// red italic
reditalic: chalk.red.italic;
// red underline
redul: chalk.red.underline;
// red strike
redstrike: chalk.red.strikethrough;
// red dim
reddim: chalk.red.dim;
// blue
blue: chalk.blue;
// blue bold
bluebold: chalk.blue.bold;
// blue dim
bluedim: chalk.blue.dim;
// blue italic
blueitalic: chalk.blue.italic;
// green
green: chalk.green;
// green bold
greenbold: chalk.green.bold;
// green dim
greendim: chalk.green.dim;
// green italic
greenitalic: chalk.green.italic;

// TEXT-STYLES //

// bold text
bold: chalk.bold;
// dim text
dim: chalk.dim;
// italic text
italic: chalk.italic;
// underline
ul: chalk.underline;
// inverse - invert bg and fg
invert: chalk.inverse;
// strikethrough
strike: chalk.strikethrough;
// bold italic
bolditalic: chalk.bold.italic;
// bold dim
bolddim: chalk.bold.dim;
// dim italic
dimitalic: chalk.dim.italic;
// dim underline
dimul: chalk.dim.underline;
// italic underline
italicul: chalk.italic.underline;
;-----

*/
```

Comment: 'pP' here ... is just short for 'promptProperty'

Comment: If this code is too confusing with Colors.js code in it ... I can rewrite the class without Colors.js to simplify it.

Comment: Okay so I got no response and worked on this problem ceaslessly :) and here is test code that wrote that works for what I needed and possibly will help other coders too:

Comment: Create project directory called 'inquirtest-cli' and CD to it then in terminal run 'npm init' overwrite package.json created with the below package.json, then create a sub-directory called bin in your project directory, then create a main file 'inquirtest.js', then in project directory run 'sudo npm link' which will enable you to just type 'inq' in terminal at any directory and it will run the main code.

package.json content:

Comment: Also do command 'npm i colors inquirer' to install colors js and inquirer js  ...note! here I also installed commander js ... but I never called it in the code so remove it in package.json dependencies ... or leave in and npm install it like colors and inquirer. I accidentally included it for changing the code later to use commander in a more advanced cli

Comment: This is just a simple very  basic CLI showing a simple organized way to use inquirer.js with async await ... instead of .then() syntax and getting the answers to user prompts :) enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Create project directory called 'inquirtest-cli' and CD to it then/n in terminal run 'npm init' overwrite package.json created with the/n below package.json, then create a sub-directory called bin in your/n project directory, then create a main file 'inquirtest.js', then in /nproject directory run 'sudo npm link' which will enable you to just type/n 'inq' in terminal at any directory and it will run the main code. /npackage.json content: */

// package.json

{
  "name": "inquirtest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "bin": {
    "inq": "./bin/inquirtest.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "robogenus",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "colors": "^1.4.0",
    "commander": "^5.1.0",
    "inquirer": "^7.1.0"
  }
}

// inquirtest.js

#!/usr/bin/env node

const inquirer = require('inquirer');
const colors = require('colors');

const doPrompts = () => {
        const ques = [
                {
                        type: 'input',
                        name: 'fullname',
                        message: 'What is your name? '.yellow
                },
                {
                        type: 'list',
                        name: 'gender',
                        message: 'Select your gender: '.yellow,
                        choices: ['Male', 'Female']
                }
        ];

        return inquirer.prompt(ques);
};

const run = async () => {
        const answers = await doPrompts();
        const { fullname, gender } = answers;

        console.log(`Hi there ${fullname}! Hmm?... So you are ${gender} type gender.`);
};
```

Comment: Hey there! Is this answer supposed to be an edit to the original question, or an actual answer to the problem that you're facing? If it's the former, you should instead [edit] the question to include the modified code. If it's the latter, please indicate that it is an answer and not an edit to the question _posted as an answer_, as well as indicate the difference between your original code and the code you've answered.